# Blue image when calculating LST

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to calculate LST for my region, but the resultant output is a blue image. What might be the problem?

[image]

```
// Define the AOI
var nyeriCounty = ee.FeatureCollection('users/danielkamau20/Nyeri_county');
var aoi = nyeriCounty.geometry();

// Load Landsat 8 image collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
  .filterBounds(aoi);
  
// Function to calculate LST
function calcLST(image) {
  var kelvin = image.select('B10').multiply(0.1);
  var emissivity = image.select('B11').multiply(0.001);
  var lst = kelvin.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115 * Tb / 1.438))*(((1/ emissivity) - 1)**(1/3.5)))',
    {
      'Tb': kelvin,
      'emissivity': emissivity
    });
  return image.addBands(lst.rename('LST')).copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

// Map the function over the collection
var lstCollection = collection.map(calcLST);

// Select LST band from the first image in the collection
var lstImage = ee.Image(lstCollection.first()).select('LST');

// Display the LST image
Map.addLayer(lstImage, {min: 273, max: 323, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow']}, 'LST');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `min`/`max` values doesn't match the data you're outputting. Go to the `Layers` section, click the gear button, select `Stretch 100%`, or one of the other options. Click `Apply` to see the changes on the map. Update your `min`/`max` based on the range in that dialogue.

[image: Click the gear]

[image: Stretch]